# Getting "ERROR: for nginx Cannot start service nginx...Bind for 0.0.0.0:4088 failed: port is already allocated" error in Ubuntu for Docker

Tags: docker, ubuntu, nginx, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am learning Docker and I set up a practice app in my local machine where it runs perfectly. The app contains 4 containers, `node-app`, `mongodb`, `redis` and `nginx`. So I'm trying to deploy it in my Ubuntu 20.04 server after cloning it from my Github repository.

When I run `docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.prod.yml up -d`, it runs only two containers, `node-app` and `redis` but not `nginx` and `mongodb`. It also throws an error for `nginx` which says that the port is already in use. But I have other non-dockerized apps in my server but none of them are listening on port 4088. I tried some other ports, but the error is the same.

This is the full error while running docker-compose:

```
latest: Pulling from library/redis
a2abf6c4d29d: Pull complete
c7a4e4382001: Pull complete
4044b9ba67c9: Pull complete
c8388a79482f: Pull complete
413c8bb60be2: Pull complete
1abfd3011519: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:db485f2e245b5b3329fdc7eff4eb00f913e09d8feb9ca720788059fdc2ed8339
Status: Downloaded newer image for redis:latest
Creating docker-practice_nginx_1 ...
Creating docker-practice_nginx_1 ... error
Creating docker-practice_redis_1 ...
WARNING: Host is already in use by another container

Creating docker-practice_mongo_1 ... done
Creating docker-practice_redis_1 ... done
Creating docker-practice_node-app_1 ... done

ERROR: for nginx  Cannot start service nginx: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint docker-practice_nginx_1 (44dceb2f230809f5789f56799c20620bc46aea42defa1c5fe938b0fcd8b03600): Bind for 0.0.0.0:4088 failed: port is already allocated
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

Here's the `docker-compose.yml` code:

```
version: "3"
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:stable-alpine
    ports:
      - "4088:80"
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:ro
  node-app:
    build: .
    environment:
      - PORT=4088
    depends_on:
      - mongo
  mongo:
    image: mongo
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=zakero
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=12345
    volumes:
      - mongo-db:/data/db
  redis:
    image: redis

volumes:
  mongo-db:
```

Here's the `docker-compose.prod.yml` code:

```
version: "3"
services:
  nginx:
    ports:
      - "4088:80"
      - "4088:443"
  node-app:
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        NODE_ENV: production
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=production
      - MONGO_USER=boomboom
      - MONGO_PASSWORD=12345
      - SESSION_SECRET=secret
    command: node index.js

  mongo:
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=boomboom
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=12345
```

Here's the `nginx/default.conf` code which is inside the root directory of the project:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    location /api {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_pass http://node-app:4088;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

This is the Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:17
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json .

ARG NODE_ENV
RUN if [ "$NODE_ENV" = "development" ]; \
        then npm install; \
        else npm install --only=production; \
        fi

COPY . ./
ENV PORT 4088
EXPOSE $PORT
CMD [ "node", "index.js" ]
```

PS.

1. There's another .env file which has `PORT=4088` listed.
2. My node-app is also listening on port 4088.
3. There is no `default.conf` file in my /etc/nginx/conf.d directory. All of my non-dockerized apps' conf files are in ```/etc/nginx/sites-available directory.

I can't figure out what the issue is here. Somebody please help.

Also please let me know what else you need to see from the server.

Comment: You `nginx` service in trying to bind 2 ports (80 and 433) to 4088. This will never work since you can't have one port on your host mappen to two different ports on your container.

Comment: @super okay so I removed nginx port ```4088:443``` from docker-compose.prod.yml file. Now the docker-compose up ran perfectly but instead of 4 containers, there are two running containers, node_app and redis is running but nginx and mongo container exited.

Comment: Check the last logs of docker image , you will get to know why it exited.

Comment: @ShaktirajsinhJadeja I know what the logs says Sir, I need solutions